# How would I duplicate MySQL Delete using an offset in Elastic Search?

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I have a MySQL script that takes a database query and cuts off a certain amount of rows depending on some settings. So if I have a user with a subscription of 100,000 things, and the user uploads 110,000, the script cuts off the last 10,000.

Here is the MySQL script:

```
DELETE FROM `my_table`
  WHERE id <= (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
      SELECT id
      FROM `my_table`
      WHERE some_id = $this->id
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET $max
    ) sp
```

Where max is 100,000

Which will delete any extra, I have since started implementing Elastic Search, and I am up to trying to duplicate this functionality but I don't know where to start because I am not that versed with this software just yet.

I have been looking at the deleteByQuery method in the PHP API, but I don't see anything about offsets or anything like that.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it will delete extra records

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id IN (
     SELECT id
     WHERE some_id = $this->id
     ORDER BY id ASC
     LIMIT $maxRecordsAllowed, $countHowManyToDelete
)
```

Comment: Sorry I may have been to vague, my MySQL works, i'm trying to duplicate that functionality using ElasticSearch